# How can I give an input to custom policy in checkov static code analysis

Tags: python, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, checkov

How can I give or supply an input to [checkov's](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) custom policy in python?
For example, I want to check if terraform plan output json file has the values that I defined, in the resources, or the names of the resource are expected as I defined.

So far I created custom policy and runs on a terraform output json file, and it works. Now I want to enhance it to read of takes an input argument to the policy and checks accordingly.

Comment: Please share the code you already have and add as much detail as possible

Comment: My code is almost like the sample custom policy documentation [here](https://www.checkov.io/3.Custom%20Policies/Python%20Custom%20Policies.html)  The only missing part in the doc is how I can give the input parameters the `scan_resource_conf` function, and I cannot find any other good resource on this.

Comment: @kini_dot if I understnad you correctly, you want to control the parameters to `scan_resource_conf`, but `checkov` is actually just reading the files and seperates all resources in a file to a `conf` which the above function gets.
Do you want to do something else rather than check part of your resource?